# Trim certain characters from a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, strings, regex

I want to remove not only spaces, but certain characters, as well from the beginning or end of a JavaScript string.

```
function trim(str, characters) {
  var c_array = characters.split('');
  var result  = '';

  for (var i=0; i < characters.length; i++)
    result += '\\' + c_array[i];

  return str.replace(new RegExp('^[' + result + ']+|['+ result +']+$', 'g'), '');
}
```

The function can be used as follows:

```
trim(' - hello**   +', '+*- ');
```

The escaping is required as `+ * .` etc. would be used in the regular expression. Is there a better way to trim any character in JavaScript? Or a better way to do the escaping, as not every character needs it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many different ways to tackle trimming [strings](/questions/tagged/strings), a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) is probably the most popular, and there are lots of blogs and performance tests out there, (<kbd>[one such blog](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript)</kbd>), that you can look at and decide which is best.

So continuing along the lines that you have demonstrated, then this may be of some help to you.

Javascript

```
/*jslint maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */

var trim = (function () {
    "use strict";

    function escapeRegex(string) {
        return string.replace(/[\[\](){}?*+\^$\\.|\-]/g, "\\$&");
    }

    return function trim(str, characters, flags) {
        flags = flags || "g";
        if (typeof str !== "string" || typeof characters !== "string" || typeof flags !== "string") {
            throw new TypeError("argument must be string");
        }

        if (!/^[gi]*$/.test(flags)) {
            throw new TypeError("Invalid flags supplied '" + flags.match(new RegExp("[^gi]*")) + "'");
        }

        characters = escapeRegex(characters);

        return str.replace(new RegExp("^[" + characters + "]+|[" + characters + "]+$", flags), '');
    };
}());

/*jslint devel: true */

console.log(trim(" - hello** +", "+*- "));
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/QNPa8/)</kbd>

Of course, you can customise which characters you wish to escape, or flags to test for, as per your own needs. <kbd>[Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)</kbd>

Comment: Good solution, but please use following function to determine if the parameter is a string:
`var isString = function(str) { return typeof str == 'string' || str instanceof String; };`
If you try to use a string like this `new String('123')` it won't work...

Comment: If that was a concern then I would probably go for `Object.prototype.toString.call(str) === '[object String]'` as a safer option.